# How to call conditional statements on template tags with no arguments django

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I'm trying to display html content based on what a template tag function returns.

**template.html**

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{% if return_something == True %}
  # display something
{% endif %}
```

**custom_tags.py**

```
from my_app.models import MyModel

@register.simple_tag()
def return_something():
    if MyModel.objects.filter(active=True).exists()
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

How do I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simple tags support an `as` syntax to set the context as a variable.

```
{% return_something as something %}
{% if something %}
```

(Note, with boolean values you should usually avoid explicitly comparing them with True or False.)

Comment: That doesn't work I get a 'return_something' received too many positional arguments.  I'm using django 1.8

Comment: Well, that functionality was introduced in Django 1.9. But you shouldn't be using Django 1.8 *anyway*; it is several years old and unsupported, and therefore insecure. You should update to a newer version.

Comment: That's what I tell my boss everyday. Any solution for it other than that though?

Comment: You will have to rewrite it as an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) instead. But when you do upgrade, you'd need to change it back, as those have been removed.